# JavaScript function for totalling up prices connected to a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to create a script, but it won't work and I can't figure out as to why...

JS

```js
var itmlist = document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0];
var event = document.getElementsByName('event[]')[0];
var price = document.querySelector('[data-price]');
var ttlprice = 0;

function totalPrice() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < itmlist.length; i++) {
    if (chk.checked) {
      ttlprice = price + ttlprice;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = ttlprice;
}

totalPrice();
```

```html
<!-- HTML for total text box -->
<section id="checkCost">
  <h2>Total cost</h2>
  Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10">
</section>

<!-- HTML for items (Multiple items) -->

<div class="item">
  <span class="eventTitle">Summer F</span>
  <span class="eventStartDate">2020-12-07</span>
  <span class="eventEndDate">2020-12-07</span>
  <span class="catDesc">Fam</span>
  <span class="venueName">Baltic</span>
  <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
  <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="0.00"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your function is called `totalP` but you are calling `totalPrice()`.

Comment: No, thats a mistake I made when posting the question, its totalPrice in my project

Comment: `document.getElementById("total").value` The input doesn't have an `id`. It has a `name="total"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message if you run the posted code is

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null",

So from that we can deduce that the statement `document.getElementById("total")` is null (its the only place you are trying to assign property `value`)

If we look at the html element in question `<input type="text" name="total" size="10">` we can see that it has no Id set, despite you trying to access it by Id (`getElementById`). A simple solution may be to add an Id to the html element:

`<input id="total" type="text" name="total" size="10">`

After further investigation, the code also has several other problems

- the calculation will not be run when clicking the checkboxes, so this can be fixed by adding an event handler to the checkboxes to re-run the calculation
- itmlist is only selecting the first item, so will not sum all of the checked items

I have posted a code which is modified from yours and works with multiple items

```js
function totalPrice() {
  var itmlist = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  var ttlprice = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < itmlist.length; i++) {
    var check = itmlist[i].getElementsByClassName("price-box")[0];
    if (check.checked) {
      ttlprice += parseInt(check.dataset.price);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("txtTotalPrice").value = ttlprice;
}

totalPrice();
```

```html
<!-- HTML for total text box -->
<section id="checkCost">
  <h2>Total cost</h2>
  Total <input id="txtTotalPrice" type="text" name="total" size="10">
</section>

<!-- HTML for items (Multiple items) -->

<div class="item">
  <span class="eventTitle">Summer F</span>
  <span class="eventStartDate">2020-12-07</span>
  <span class="eventEndDate">2020-12-07</span>
  <span class="catDesc">Fam</span>
  <span class="venueName">Baltic</span>
  <span class="eventPrice">5.00</span>
  <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" class="price-box" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="5" onclick="totalPrice()"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span class="eventTitle">Summer F</span>
  <span class="eventStartDate">2020-12-07</span>
  <span class="eventEndDate">2020-12-07</span>
  <span class="catDesc">Fam</span>
  <span class="venueName">Baltic</span>
  <span class="eventPrice">10.00</span>
  <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" class="price-box" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="10" onclick="totalPrice()"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is indeed the issue, it is better to close it as a typo as it has no long term value to the site